# Instalacion Spyder en Centos muestra ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

Tags: python, centos, anaconda, spyder, impala

He levantado una una maquina virtual de cloudera que contiene una instalacion centos que contiene las herramientas  hue, impala, etc.

Mi objetivo era conectarme desde mi maquina local y conectarme mediante impala odbc para realizar sentencias sql desde python. No pude lograr la conexion porque al hacer ping a la IP de mi maquina virtual no logro conectarme.

Por ellos decidi instalar Anaconda en la maquina virtual para intentar hacer la conexion desde ahi. Descargue el instalador de anaconda y la instalacion no me dio problemas, sin embargo cuando ejecuto en un shell el comando spyder se me presenta el siguiente error:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ spyder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cloudera/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 204, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cloudera/anaconda3/bin/spyder", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/cloudera/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 186, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/home/cloudera/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 48, in <module>
    requirements.check_qt()
  File "/home/cloudera/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/requirements.py", line 41, in check_qt
    import qtpy
  File "/home/cloudera/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 210, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
(base) [cloudera@quickstart ~]$
```

Intente instalar el modulo pyside pero al parecer no se resuelve el error. De lo que indica el menu no encuentra un modulo, pero y ano tengo idea de como instalarlo para resolver el problema.

UPDATE:
Realice la instalacion de PyQt5 desde anaconda: conda install -c anaconda pyqt como indicaron en el comentario pero se muestra lo siguiente:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ spyder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cloudera/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 22, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ImportError: libEGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cloudera/anaconda3/bin/spyder", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/cloudera/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 186, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/home/cloudera/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 90, in <module>
    from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets  # analysis:ignore
  File "/home/cloudera/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage as QWebEnginePage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets'
(base) [cloudera@quickstart ~]$
```

Agradezco si alguien me puede dar una idea de como solucionarlo.

Saludos,
Daniel Vera

Comment: instala PyQt5 desde anaconda: `conda install -c anaconda pyqt` ya que spyder requiere al menos uno de los binding de Qt.

Comment: Logre instalarlo, sin embargo ahora se presenta lo siguiente:

Comment: edita tu pregunta y añade como actualizacion lo que señale en mi comentario anterior y tu mensaje de error

Comment: instala el paquete `qt5-qtbase-devel`: `sudo dnf install qt5-qtbase-devel`

Comment: dnf es un comando? Porque no lo reconoce el prompt

Comment: ¿Qué version de centos usas?

Comment: CentOS release 6.7

Comment: prueba con `yum`: `sudo yum install qt5-qtbase-devel`

Comment: La instalcion de realizo sin errores, sin embargo aparece el mismo mensaje al ejecutar spyder.

Comment: instala `mesa-libEGL-devel`: `sudo yum install mesa-libEGL-devel` ¿Tu centos tiene interfaz gráfica?

Comment: Asi es. Tiene interfaz grafica

Comment: Ahora si se pudo ejecutar. Me pregunto si tendre los mismos problemas para instalar el impala odbc, Pero bueno ya es un avance. Muchas gracias.